# Error when attempting to build a UWP app in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

The specific error is  `"Cannot find type Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.XamlCompositionBrushBase in module Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd"`. The error comes from a targets file in the Windows version 14393 SDK, specifically the `Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets` file, and different errors appear if I set my minimum platform to different versions. Cleaning and rebuilding the solution or project has done nothing, switching from ARM to x86 or x64 does nothing, reinstalling Visual studio did nothing, completely commenting out all my Xaml does nothing.

Comment: Do you have the corresponding SDK versions installed on your device?

Comment: Yes, I have all the necessary SDKs.

Answer (score 4):

[XamlCompositionBrushBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.xamlcompositionbrushbase) requires SDK 15063, so that has to be your app's minimum and target version (or higher).  Usually your target is the same as the OS you're developing on, which should be equal to or higher than your minimum version.

You need to look under the **Windows 10 requirements** section of the docs when looking at APIs:

```
Device family
Windows 10 Creators Update (introduced v10.0.15063.0) 

API contract
Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract (introduced v4)
```